# CSS table id selection

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to select `#left` and `#right` but I'm not sure of how to do so.

```
<table class="pricetable">
    <tr>
        <td id="left">test</td>
        <td id="right">test1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've tried `#right.pricetable td{}` but it doesn't work. Ideas?

Comment: [This is a useful read](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/css-selectors/) for you.

Answer (score 3):

In CSS, id should be unique, so you can just use

```
#right { ...}
```

Comment: yeah this I know, but I wanted to specify class as well. thanks though

Answer (score 2):

```
.pricetable td#left
```

Selectors work from left to right. In addition, IDs should be unique.

Answer (score 1):

It would either be

```
#right
```

or

```
.pricetable td#right
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS selectors work left to right. `#right.pricetable` is saying look for an element with `id=right AND class = pricetable`.

The id is specific enough that `#left` or `#right` by themselves will work.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
.pricetable td#left{

 }
.pricetable td#right{

}
```

or if same style for both

use

```
.pricetable td#left,.pricetable td#right{

     }
```

or simply

```
#right { ...}

#left{...}
```

as **id's are unique**

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what everyone else is saying - although, you don't have to be super specific with selectors though unless you anticipate using more of the same ID, which is a nono. So you could get away with `#left` and `#right` or be as specific as `.pricetable #left` and `.pricetable #right`. Unless you really wanted to get crazy and `table.pricetable tr td#left, table.pricetable tr td#right`